# How to print OpenDocument Text using OdfToolkit?

Tags: java, odt, odftoolkit

Can I print a ODF text document using OdfToolkit? Or is there a open source lib that provide this usability? I can't find any. Target machine must not have installed Open/Libre Office.

Alternatively how to print files using installed Open/Libre Office binaries?

I want to control printer properties like two side printing and of course target printer.

Regards

Comment: Currently I'm using [OdfToolkit](http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/) to generate ODT, [JODConverter](http://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/) to convert ODT to PDF (requires OpenOffice) and [PDFRenderer](http://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer) to print. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OdfToolkit provides document manipulation functionality. Rendering or printing is not covered. You should use UNO for printing. Take a look at http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Java/Office/DocumentHandling